# error while adding plugin in cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am getting below error while adding the plugin com.hiddentao.cordova.FilePath.

```
Failed to restore plugin "com.hiddentao.cordova.FilePath" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again.
 Error: Failed to fetch plugin com.hiddentao.cordova.FilePath@https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath.git via registry.
```

When i build from cordova build android i am getting above error. I am not sure what am i doing wrong.

Here is the code from config.xml

```
<plugin name="com.hiddentao.cordova.filepath.FilePath" spec="https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath.git" />
```

Comment: The name of the plugin is wrong, it is: cordova-plugin-filepath

Comment: as per this link https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath/blob/master/plugin.xml line 42. Plugin is like this com.hiddentao.cordova.filepath.FilePath

Comment: Joerg is right. When you install plugin by cli : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath. config.xml has <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.0.2" />